Metadata.bin file not found on initial gradle sync with Android Studio Koala - 2024.1.1
I recently updated Android Studio from Chipmunk version - 2021.2.1 to Koala version - 2024.1.1.
Now, when I open my projects, the gradle synchronization starts and always ends with:
C:\Users\[MY_USER]\.gradle\caches\8.7\groovy-dsl\8a1452873841172f5abf6c65b3637f25\metadata.bin (The specified file could not be found).
I found a solution here (Android - Error while creating a jetpack compose project on Android Studio), deleting the C:\Users\[MY_USER]\.gradle\caches folder, but I have to do it every day for any project.
I also tried completely uninstalling Android Studio and reinstalling it, but nothing changed.
Does anyone have a more permanent solution in mind?

Сhanging the gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties may help

It was resolved by deleting the '[MY_USER].gradle\caches\8.7\groovy-dsl\8a1452873841172f5abf6c65b3637f25' folder.
Please refer to the blog below.
https://jiji-gilog.tistory.com/28
